# How to automate software using AWS codepipeline with jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, devops, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I am novice at Jenkins. My demo project built in github and with AWS codedeploy I can run my project succesfully. If I use AWS codepipeline without Jenkins, whatever changed in github its automatically integrated and run the project. So I want to use Jenkins, if codes have successfully built then it should run. So when I add jenkins in AWS codepipeline and integrated with my jenkins server this process has not run and it just processing in build section. What is the error or it's not integrated with jenkins? So what should I do? Kindly help me.

Comment: Hello. This is your first question. You'll need to provide more information to get a more accurate answer and to help the community. Please show examples of what you've done and why it's not working, among other information that can help the community to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If your project is simple single html page then no need of using build provider.
- If your project is based on maven or gradle then Jenkins will build the job and generate the output artifact file as zip and stored in jenkins workplace. Then these output artifact file is taken as input artifact file for next stage mostly for deployment purpose.

For using jenkins as Build Provider in AWS CodePipeline you should use IAM role for accessing between Jenkins server and AWS CodePipeline.

Purpose of IAM role:

- Jenkins server will get input artifact files from the source provider such as AWS S3 bucket, GitHub.
- Jenkins server will poll SCM based on Build trigger in your job.
- After build successful, Jenkins server will store the output artifact file as zip in jenkins workplace as I mentioned earlier.
- These output artifact file is taken as input for next stage. For example, Artefact file should be deployed on AWS CodeDeploy.

Thanks